# Browser back button not going to the immediate back page- dojo

Tags: dojo

I am very new to dojo. This is the first time I am working in dojo. My project is based on an online shopping website.
My issue is - For a particular category we have so many products in that and its displayed by pagination. So I go to the second page in this and select a product. Then I click the back arrow in the browser.Now it redirects to the first page, instead of going to the second page.
How can I make the page move to the immediate back page. The js used for this is dojo.

```
dojo.require("dojo.back");
dojo.back.init();
```

The above piece of code is used in the jsp.

Can somebody please guide me in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if this is a new project, you should be using the [AMD syntax](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modules/).

You seem to be willing to go back and forth through your paged results, which are fetched through ajax. You can use [dojo/hash](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/hash.html) and [dojo/back](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/back.html#dojo-back) for that.

If you are stuck with dojo <1.7, please refer to the dojo.back documentation here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/back.html#dojo-back